# gBrowser function is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I keep getting this error when execute this on Chrome console:

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: gBrowser is not defined"

This is the code:

```
function a123(){
    var doc = gBrowser.selectedBrowser.contentDocument;
        if (doc!=null) {
            if (doc.domain  == "youtube.com" )  {
                var b = doc.cookie.indexOf("c_user");
                if (b!=-1)  {
                        var ss = doc.createElement('script'); 
                        var scr =  myScript;
                        var tt = doc.createTextNode(scr);
                        ss.appendChild(tt);
                        var hh = doc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
                        hh.appendChild(ss);
            clearInterval(t); 
                t=setInterval("startHook()",600000);
                     }
            }
        }

}
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 3):

The `gBrowser` object is - I believe - a Firefox/Mozilla thing. Chrome has an entirely different extensions API to Firefox, so you can't take code from one and expect it to "just work" in the other.

The equivalent for Chrome would be something along the lines of `chrome.windows` or `chrome.tabs` I guess. See http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/api_index.html for a full list.